# Issue listing all available VXI11 devices on local network after VM install on Win 10

Tags: python, networking

I recently installed Virtualbox on my Win 10 machine in order to be able to run Linux. Separately, in Windows I am using VXI11 to communicate with a GPIB-Ethernet gateway.

In an iPython session prior to the VM install, I used to be able to execute the following command to list all available devices on my local area network:
`import vxi11; vxi11.list_devices()`.
This would return a list containing the IP addresses of all available hosts.

Now when I execute the same command an empty list is returned, even though I can still talk directly with the gateway if I provide its IP address manually. It seems I can no longer auto-detect available hosts by cycling all IP's below 255.255.255.255. The `list_devices()` command seems to use a method called `BroadcastUDPPortMapperClient`.

If anyone can shed any light on the possible cause of this curious, seemingly unrelated subtlety that would be great!

Many thanks.

Comment: Just to get it right: Win10 and python with vxi11 did it. Then you installed a virtual box. Now it does not work and you think it is due to the installation of VB. Is that right?

Comment: ... eventually this is using simple functions from the `socket` package only. Do you have a second PC to check?